# How to send photo from Android Phone to Domino Server

Tags: android, ajax, android-camera, lotus-domino

How can I send the image from my phone back to a Domino Server.
I am using the xmlhttprequest object and posting the Base64 image data into a RichText Field on my Form.
 I have confirmed that it is not truncating the data. I cannot figure out what to do with the data to display it as an image.

I have tried the  tag and putting the Base64 text as the img src. This just shows the std broken image icon in my browser.

Please help.. I am on day 7 of trying to get this to work.
Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: Or change your way to upload, [see](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decode the Base64 data into an actual attachment when saving the document.  You can then just put the URL for the image attachment into an img tag.  What is it in my answer [here](/questions/4731217/is-it-possible-to-upload-an-image-file-using-ajax-to-domino-server) that you are not getting?

Comment: Kerr, I have done all the steps that you have suggested. Please review my code. Thank you for taking the time to help me. Mike